# How to sort the columns of a CSV file by the ratio of two columns?

Tags: bash, awk

I have a CSV file like this:

```
bear,1,2
fish,3,4
cats,1,5
mice,3,3
```

I want to sort it, from highest to lowest, by the ratio of column 2 and 3. E.g.:

```
bear,1,2 # 1/2 = 0.5
fish,3,4 # 3/4 = 0.75
cats,1,5 # 1/5 = 0.2
mice,3,3 # 3/3 = 1
```

This would be sorted like this:

```
mice,3,3
fish,3,4
bear,1,2
cats,1,5
```

- How can I sort the columns from highest to lowest by the ratio of the two numbers in column 2 and 3?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
awk 'BEGIN { FS = OFS = ","} {$4 = $2/$3; print}' | sort -k4,4nr -t, | sed 's/,[^,]*$//' inputfile
```

or using GNU AWK (`gawk`):

```
awk -F, '{a[$3/$2] = $3/$2; b[$3/$2] = $0} END {c = asort(a); for (i = 1; i <= c; i++) print b[a[i]]}' inputfile
```

The methods above are better than the following, but this is more efficient than another answer which uses Bash and various utilities:

```
while IFS=, read animal dividend divisor
do
    quotient=$(echo "scale=4; $dividend/$divisor" | bc)
    echo "$animal,$dividend,$divisor,$quotient"
done < inputfile | sort -k4,4nr -t, | sed 's/,[^,]*$//'
```

As a one-liner:

```
while IFS=, read animal dividend divisor; do quotient=$(echo "scale=4; $dividend/$divisor" | bc); echo "$animal,$dividend,$divisor,$quotient"; done < inputfile | sort -k4,4nr -t | sed 's/,[^,]*$//'
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not just create another column that holds the ratio of the second and third columns and then sort on that column?

Answer (score 1):

bash is not meant for stuff like that - pick your own favorite programming language, and do it there.

If you insist... here is an example:

```
a=( `cut -d "," -f 2 mat.csv` ); b=( `cut -d "," -f 3 mat.csv` );for i in {0..3};do (echo -n `head -n $((i+1)) mat.csv|tail -1`" "; echo "scale=4;${a[i]}/${b[i]}"|bc) ;done|sort -k 2 -r
```

Modify filename and length.

Comment: I.e. "pick your favorite programming language which is distinct from bash ..." :)